# ERROR: Cannot install en-core-web-trf because these package versions have conflicting dependencies

Tags: python, pip, nlp, spacy

I use the following commands (from spacy website [here](https://spacy.io/usage)) to install spacy and en_core_web_trf under Windows 10 home 64 bit, however, I have encountered problems while running the last (third line) command.

```
pip install -U pip setuptools wheel
pip install -U spacy
python -m spacy download en_core_web_trf
```

Error:

```
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of en-core-web-trf to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
ERROR: Cannot install en-core-web-trf because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    spacy-transformers 1.1.4 depends on torch>=1.6.0
    spacy-transformers 1.1.3 depends on torch>=1.6.0
    spacy-transformers 1.1.2 depends on torch>=1.6.0

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies
```

Anyone knows how to solve it? thanks! I was stuck here for the whole evening.

Error update after uninstalling the spacy and reinstall it with `pip install spacy-transformers -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`

```
ERROR: Cannot install spacy-transformers==0.5.0, spacy-transformers==0.5.1, spacy-transformers==0.5.2, spacy-transformers==0.5.3, spacy-transformers==0.6.1, spacy-transformers==0.6.2, spacy-transformers==1.0.0, spacy-transformers==1.0.1, spacy-transformers==1.0.2, spacy-transformers==1.0.3, spacy-transformers==1.0.4, spacy-transformers==1.0.5, spacy-transformers==1.0.6, spacy-transformers==1.1.0, spacy-transformers==1.1.1, spacy-transformers==1.1.2, spacy-transformers==1.1.3 and spacy-transformers==1.1.4 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    spacy-transformers 1.1.4 depends on torch>=1.6.0
    spacy-transformers 1.1.3 depends on torch>=1.6.0
    spacy-transformers 1.1.2 depends on torch>=1.6.0
    spacy-transformers 1.1.1 depends on torch>=1.6.0
    spacy-transformers 1.1.0 depends on torch>=1.6.0
    spacy-transformers 1.0.6 depends on torch>=1.5.0
    spacy-transformers 1.0.5 depends on torch>=1.5.0
    spacy-transformers 1.0.4 depends on torch>=1.5.0
    spacy-transformers 1.0.3 depends on torch>=1.5.0
    spacy-transformers 1.0.2 depends on torch>=1.5.0
    spacy-transformers 1.0.1 depends on torch>=1.5.0
    spacy-transformers 1.0.0 depends on torch>=1.5.0
    spacy-transformers 0.6.2 depends on spacy<2.4.0 and >=2.3.0
    spacy-transformers 0.6.1 depends on spacy<2.4.0 and >=2.3.0
    spacy-transformers 0.5.3 depends on spacy<2.3.0 and >=2.2.1
    spacy-transformers 0.5.2 depends on spacy<2.3.0 and >=2.2.1
    spacy-transformers 0.5.1 depends on spacy<2.3.0 and >=2.2.1
    spacy-transformers 0.5.0 depends on spacy<2.3.0 and >=2.2.1

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Information for someone who will have the same problem with me.

The mentioned problem was finally not solved, at least I tried to reinstall packages, reinstall python (totally uninstalled it before reinstalling). Nothing worked for me.

How did I avoid this finally?

I uninstalled the python completely.

Install Anaconda (latest version), while installing the Anaconda, the pip and python are also installed by default. Then I use `pip install XX` in the windows command line, no matter to install spacy, or to install the requirements.txt, all work well. That's how did I avoid the above mentioned problem.

Hope it is helpful for someone who also have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by installing PyTorch. That's what that "conflict" means. I would also warn that you should make sure that spaCy, PyTorch, and Python are all compatible. For me that means the following:

1. Install Python 3.10
2. Install CUDA 12.1
3. Create a Python 3.10 venv
4. Install PyTorch in venv
5. Install GPU spaCy
6. Install the particular spaCy core

The commands I ran after installing CUDA 12.1 and Python 3.10 were:

```
\Python310\python.exe -m venv .venv
.\.venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu121
pip install -U pip setuptools wheel
pip install -U 'spacy[cuda12x]'
python -m spacy download en_core_web_trf
```

Answer (score -1):

try:
`pip uninstall spacy-transformers 1.1.4`
`pip uninstall spacy-transformers 1.1.3`
`pip uninstall spacy-transformers 1.1.2`
then execute:

```
pip install spacy-transformers -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

You can find the complete installation processus on https://pypi.org/project/spacy-transformers/

Comment: Thanks, after using pip uninstall, I got warning: WARNING: Skipping spacy-transformers as it is not installed.

Comment: sorry, use `pip uninstall spacy` an then `pip install spacy-transformers -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`

Comment: thanks, but why? after I uninstall the spacy, I will need to install it again, right? because my purpose is to install it

Comment: yes but with the second command

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately, it does not work, I have got the similar error again, see the updated error, thanks